# How do i create an S60 app that writes to idle/Active screen?

Tags: api, symbian, s60

I would like to write a replacement for the S60 Active Screen (app that runs in the idle screen). But I can't find any documentation covering how to write/draw to the idle/active screen API's for S60 3rd edition.

I dont mind if they are for C++ or Python bindings.

Can anyone point me to some docs/examples?

PS I know this can be done, because there is an app called Handy Shell which replaces the 'Symbian active screen'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to register for focus group changes and bring your app to the foreground when the current idle screen app comes to the foreground.

There are a couple of ways to do this - the simplest is via `HandleWsEventL()` in your AppUi class. Over-ride [HandleWsEventL()](http://www.symbian.com/Developer/techlib/v70sdocs/doc_source/reference/cpp/UIControlFramework/CCoeAppUiClass.html#%3a%3aCCoeAppUi%3a%3aHandleWsEventL()) and check for `EEventFocusGroupChanged` events. At this point you can use `RWsSession::GetFocusWindowGroup()` to get the Window Group ID of the app brought to the foreground. If it is the idle screen, bring yourself to the foreground.

(This assumes you have determined the idle screen Window Group ID from the Idle UID using `TApaTaskList::FindApp()` previously. The UID in S60 3rd FP2 on is 0x102750F0. Pre-FP2 it is 0x101fd64c).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how HandyShell does this. But the [Nokia Knowledge Base says](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/KIS001196_-_Restrictions_in_developing_customised_Active_Idle_plug-ins), it's restricted and not available for 3rd parties...

Comment: maybe there is another way... can i directly draw to screen? like profimail does when a mail comes in?